# How to convert arbitrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?

Tags: json, csv, jq

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), how can arbitrary JSON encoding an array of shallow objects be converted to CSV?

There are plenty of Q&As on this site that cover specific data models which hard-code the fields, but answers to this question should work given any JSON, with the only restriction that it's an array of objects with scalar properties (no deep/complex/sub-objects, as flattening these is another question). The result should contain a header row giving the field names. Preference will be given to answers that preserve the field order of the first object, but it's not a requirement. Results may enclose all cells with double-quotes, or only enclose those that require quoting (e.g. 'a,b').

### Examples

1. Input:

   ```
   [
       {"code": "NSW", "name": "New South Wales", "level":"state", "country": "AU"},
       {"code": "AB", "name": "Alberta", "level":"province", "country": "CA"},
       {"code": "ABD", "name": "Aberdeenshire", "level":"council area", "country": "GB"},
       {"code": "AK", "name": "Alaska", "level":"state", "country": "US"}
   ]
   ```

   Possible output:

   ```
   code,name,level,country
   NSW,New South Wales,state,AU
   AB,Alberta,province,CA
   ABD,Aberdeenshire,council area,GB
   AK,Alaska,state,US
   ```

   Possible output:

   ```
   "code","name","level","country"
   "NSW","New South Wales","state","AU"
   "AB","Alberta","province","CA"
   "ABD","Aberdeenshire","council area","GB"
   "AK","Alaska","state","US"
   ```
2. Input:

   ```
   [
       {"name": "bang", "value": "!", "level": 0},
       {"name": "letters", "value": "a,b,c", "level": 0},
       {"name": "letters", "value": "x,y,z", "level": 1},
       {"name": "bang", "value": "\"!\"", "level": 1}
   ]
   ```

   Possible output:

   ```
   name,value,level
   bang,!,0
   letters,"a,b,c",0
   letters,"x,y,z",1
   bang,"""!""",0
   ```

   Possible output:

   ```
   "name","value","level"
   "bang","!","0"
   "letters","a,b,c","0"
   "letters","x,y,z","1"
   "bang","""!""","1"
   ```

Comment: Three-plus years later ... a generic `json2csv` is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242240/jq-object-cannot-be-csv-formatted-only-array

Comment: Even later to the party ;) Here is another generic solution that allows reverse transforms: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69230818/how-to-convert-arbitrary-nested-json-to-csv-with-jq-so-you-can-convert-it-back?noredirect=1#comment122364748_69230818

Answer (score 305):

First, obtain an array containing all the different object property names in your object array input. Those will be the columns of your CSV:

```
(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols
```

Then, for each object in the object array input, map the column names you obtained to the corresponding properties in the object. Those will be the rows of your CSV.

```
map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows
```

Finally, put the column names before the rows, as a header for the CSV, and pass the resulting row stream to the `@csv` filter.

```
$cols, $rows[] | @csv
```

All together now. Remember to use the `-r` flag to get the result as a raw string:

```
jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv'
```

Comment: It's nice that your solution captures all of the property names from all rows, rather than just the first. I wonder what the performance implications of this  are for very large documents, though. P.S. If you want, you can get rid of the `$rows` variable assignment by just inlining it: `(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | $cols, map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.]))[] | @csv`

Comment: Thanks, Jordan! I am aware that `$rows` does not have to be assigned to a variable; I just thought assigning it to a variable made the explanation nicer.

Comment: consider converting the row value | string in case there's nested arrays or maps.

Comment: Good suggestion, @TJR. Maybe if there are nested structures, jq should recurse into them and make their values into columns as well

Comment: How would this differ if the JSON was in a file and you wanted to filter out some specific data to CSV?

Comment: Would appropriate use of the command then be: _your last code block_ and then `my.json > my.csv` on the same line?

Answer (score 183):

### The Skinny

```
jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, map([.[ $keys[] ]])[] | @csv'
```

or:

```
jq -r '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | ([$keys] + map([.[ $keys[] ]])) [] | @csv'
```

### The Details

#### Aside

Describing the details is tricky because jq is stream-oriented, meaning it operates on a sequence of JSON data, rather than a single value. The input JSON stream gets converted to some internal type which is passed through the filters, then encoded in an output stream at program's end. The internal type isn't modeled by JSON, and doesn't exist as a named type. It's most easily demonstrated by examining the output of a bare index (`.[]`) or the comma operator (examining it directly could be done with a debugger, but that would be in terms of jq's internal data types, rather than the conceptual data types behind JSON).

> ```
> $ jq -c '.[]' <<<'["a", "b"]'
> "a"
> "b"
> $ jq -cn '"a", "b"'
> "a"
> "b"
> ```

Note that the output isn't an array (which would be `["a", "b"]`). Compact output (the `-c` option) shows that each array element (or argument to the `,` filter) becomes a separate object in the output (each is on a separate line).

A stream is like a [JSON-seq](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7464), but uses newlines rather than [RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators) as an output separator when encoded. Consequently, this internal type is referred to by the generic term "sequence" in this answer, with "stream" being reserved for the encoded input and output.

#### Constructing the Filter

The first object's keys can be extracted with:

```
.[0] | keys_unsorted
```

Keys will generally be kept in their original order, but preserving the exact order isn't guaranteed. Consequently, they will need to be used to index the objects to get the values in the same order. This will also prevent values being in the wrong columns if some objects have a different key order.

To both output the keys as the first row and make them available for indexing, they're stored in a variable. The next stage of the pipeline then references this variable and uses the comma operator to prepend the header to the output stream.

```
(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys | $keys, ...
```

The expression after the comma is a little involved. The index operator on an object can take a sequence of strings (e.g. `"name", "value"`), returning a sequence of property values for those strings. `$keys` is an array, not a sequence, so `[]` is applied to convert it to a sequence,

```
$keys[]
```

which can then be passed to `.[]`

```
.[ $keys[] ]
```

This, too, produces a sequence, so the array constructor is used to convert it to an array.

```
[.[ $keys[] ]]
```

This expression is to be applied to a single object. `map()` is used to apply it to all objects in the outer array:

```
map([.[ $keys[] ]])
```

Lastly for this stage, this is converted to a sequence so each item becomes a separate row in the output.

```
map([.[ $keys[] ]])[]
```

Why bundle the sequence into an array within the `map` only to unbundle it outside? `map` produces an array; `.[ $keys[] ]` produces a sequence. Applying `map` to the sequence from `.[ $keys[] ]` would produce an array of sequences of values, but since sequences aren't a JSON type, so you instead get a flattened array containing all the values.

```
["NSW","AU","state","New South Wales","AB","CA","province","Alberta","ABD","GB","council area","Aberdeenshire","AK","US","state","Alaska"]
```

The values from each object need to be kept separate, so that they become separate rows in the final output.

Finally, the sequence is passed through `@csv` formatter.

#### Alternate

The items can be separated late, rather than early. Instead of using the comma operator to get a sequence (passing a sequence as the right operand), the header sequence (`$keys`) can be wrapped in an array, and `+` used to append the array of values. This still needs to be converted to a sequence before being passed to `@csv`.

Comment: Can you use `keys_unsorted` instead of `keys` to preserve the key order from the first object?

Comment: @outis - The preamble about streams is somewhat inaccurate. The simple fact is that jq filters are stream-oriented.  That is, any filter can accept a stream of JSON entities, and some filters can produce a stream of values.  There is no "new line" or any other separator between the items in a stream -- it's only when they're printed that a separator is introduced.  To see for yourself, try: jq -n -c 'reduce ("a","b") as $s (""; . + $s)'

Comment: Did something happen between when this was written and now to render it incorrect?  The problem seems to be in the map, which, breaks even on a toy example:
`$ echo '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}' |jq -r '(. | keys_unsorted) as $keys| $keys, map( [.[ $keys[] ] ])[] | @csv'` outputs
`"a","b","c"
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index number with string "a"`  on jq-1.5.

Comment: @Wyatt: take a closer look at your data and the example input. The question is about an array of objects, not a single object. Try `[{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}]`.

Comment: Working through the details of this solution taught me a LOT about jq!  For anyone else struggling with the details, it may be helpful to play with "jq -cr '(.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $array_of_keys | $array_of_keys, (.[] | [ .[$array_of_keys[]] ]) | .'", since that's how the map filter is implemented.  And remember that the "(foo) as $bar" variable assignment actually acts as a for-each that iterates over all the items in the (foo) expression (not an issue in this case, since we're pulling out the keys as a single item).

Comment: @peak: regarding new line–note I called it an "output separator" (rather than "stream separator" or similar) for just the reason you state. I've edited my answer to try to make this clearer, and to incorporate your suggestion of the term "stream".

Answer (score 27):

```
$cat test.json
[
    {"code": "NSW", "name": "New South Wales", "level":"state", "country": "AU"},
    {"code": "AB", "name": "Alberta", "level":"province", "country": "CA"},
    {"code": "ABD", "name": "Aberdeenshire", "level":"council area", "country": "GB"},
    {"code": "AK", "name": "Alaska", "level":"state", "country": "US"}
]


$ jq -r '["Code", "Name", "Level", "Country"], (.[] | [.code, .name, .level, .country]) | @tsv ' test.json
Code    Name    Level   Country
NSW New South Wales state   AU
AB  Alberta province    CA
ABD Aberdeenshire   council area    GB
AK  Alaska  state   US


$ jq -r '["Code", "Name", "Level", "Country"], (.[] | [.code, .name, .level, .country]) | @csv ' test.json
"Code","Name","Level","Country"
"NSW","New South Wales","state","AU"
"AB","Alberta","province","CA"
"ABD","Aberdeenshire","council area","GB"
"AK","Alaska","state","US"
```

Answer (score 16):

The following filter is slightly different in that it will ensure every value is converted to a string. (jq 1.5+)

```sh
# For an array of many objects
jq -f filter.jq [file]

# For many objects (not within array)
jq -s -f filter.jq [file]
```

**Filter: `filter.jq`**

```
def tocsv:
    (map(keys)
        |add
        |unique
        |sort
    ) as $cols
    |map(. as $row
        |$cols
        |map($row[.]|tostring)
    ) as $rows
    |$cols,$rows[]
    | @csv;

tocsv
```

Comment: This works good for simple JSON but what about JSON with nested properties that go down many levels?

Comment: This of course sorts the keys.  Also the output of `unique` is sorted anyway, so `unique|sort` can be simplified to `unique`.

Comment: @TJR When using this filter it is mandatory to switch on raw output using `-r` option. Otherwise all the quotes `"` become extra-escaped which is not valid CSV.

Comment: Amir: nested properties don't map to CSV.

Comment: @Amir: adding to chrishmorris' comment, this question is explicitly restricted to "array[s] of objects with scalar properties (no deep/complex/sub-objects, as flattening these is another question)".

Comment: Copy-pasters beware: `|tostring` will convert `null` and missing properties (cells) to `"null"` in the output CSV. With `|tostring`: `value,"null","null","null",value`, without `|tostring`: `value,,,,value`.

Answer (score 9):

I created a function that outputs an array of objects or arrays to csv with headers.  The columns would be in the order of the headers.

```
def to_csv($headers):
    def _object_to_csv:
        ($headers | @csv),
        (.[] | [.[$headers[]]] | @csv);
    def _array_to_csv:
        ($headers | @csv),
        (.[][:$headers|length] | @csv);
    if .[0]|type == "object"
        then _object_to_csv
        else _array_to_csv
    end;
```

So you could use it like so:

```
to_csv([ "code", "name", "level", "country" ])
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're open to using other Unix tools, [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has an `in2csv` tool:

```bash
in2csv example.json
```

Using your sample data:

```bash
> in2csv example.json
code,name,level,country
NSW,New South Wales,state,AU
AB,Alberta,province,CA
ABD,Aberdeenshire,council area,GB
AK,Alaska,state,US
```

I like the pipe approach for piping directly from `jq`:

```bash
cat example.json | in2csv -f json -
```

Answer (score 4):

This variant of Santiago's program is also safe but ensures that the key names in
the first object are used as the first column headers, in the same order as they
appear in that object:

```
def tocsv:
  if length == 0 then empty
  else
    (.[0] | keys_unsorted) as $firstkeys
    | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $allkeys
    | ($firstkeys + ($allkeys - $firstkeys)) as $cols
    | ($cols, (.[] as $row | $cols | map($row[.])))
    | @csv
  end ;

tocsv
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to just use string concatenation. If your input is a proper array:

```
# filename.txt
[
  {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"},
  {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"},
  {"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
]
```

then index with `.[]`:

```
cat filename.txt | jq -r '.[] | .field1 + ", " + .field2'
```

or if it's just line by line objects:

```
# filename.txt
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}
```

just do this:

```
cat filename.txt | jq -r '.field1 + ", " + .field2'
```

Comment: To highlight why this answer is getting downvotes:
1. it has missed the question's core, which is "arbitrary JSON" without hard-coding fields.
2. using string concatenation for conversion is bad in general, as it can result in bad data in the output, simply think about the output for `{"field1":"value1,value3", "field2":"value2"}`.

Comment: Helped me, though. Thanks Nick.

Comment: You're welcome, @RobertMuil.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a compact solution:

```
(map(keys)|add|unique)as$k|$k,(.[]|[.[$k[]]])|@csv
```

- `(map(keys) | add | unique) as $k` sets `$k` to all unique keys found in the array of objects
- `.[$k[]]` returns the object index for all keys in `$k`
- `(.[] | [ ... ])` returns an array of values for each object.