# Convert json using jq based on specific constraints

Tags: python, json, csv, filtering, jq

I have a json file 'OpenEnded_mscoco_val2014.json'.The json file contains 121,512 questions.
Here is some sample :

```
"questions": [
{
  "question": "What is the table made of?",
  "image_id": 350623,
  "question_id": 3506232
},
{
  "question": "Is the food napping on the table?",
  "image_id": 350623,
  "question_id": 3506230
},
{
  "question": "What has been upcycled to make lights?",
  "image_id": 350623,
  "question_id": 3506231
},
{
  "question": "Is this an Spanish town?",
  "image_id": 8647,
  "question_id": 86472
}
```

]

I used `jq -r '.questions | [map(.question), map(.image_id), map(.question_id)] | @csv' OpenEnded_mscoco_val2014_questions.json >> temp.csv` to convert json into csv. 
But here output in csv is question followed by image_id which is what above code does.
The expected output is :

```
"What is table made of",350623,3506232
"Is the food napping on the table?",350623,3506230
```

Also is it possible to filter only results having`image_id <= 10000` and to `group questions having same image_id`? e.g. 1,2,3 result of json can be combined  to have 3 questions, 1 image_id, 3 question_id.

EDIT : The first problem is solved by `possible duplicate question`.I would like to know if is it possible to invoke comparison operator on command line in jq for converting json file. In this case get all fields from json if `image_id <= 10000` only.

Comment: Not quite sure what your first question is here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

Comment: I would like to filter output having image_id having value <= 10000 using jq as file is too large in size so using json_load() and comparing will take a lot of memory.

Comment: 1. Please fix the question so that the example input is valid JSON. 2. If the point of the question is that (.questions | length) is so big that you don't want to have to read the whole file into memory, then please say so. (In that case, jq has a streaming parser which might be able to help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Given your input (suitably elaborated to make it valid JSON), the following query generates the CSV output as shown:

```
$ jq -r '.questions[] | [.question, .image_id, .question_id] | @csv'

"What is the table made of?",350623,3506232
"Is the food napping on the table?",350623,3506230
"What has been upcycled to make lights?",350623,3506231
"Is this an Spanish town?",8647,86472
```

The key thing to remember here is that @csv requires a flat array, but as with all jq filters, you can feed it a stream.

2) To filter using the criterion `.image_id <= 10000`, just interpose the appropriate `select/1` filter:

```
.questions[]
| select(.image_id <= 10000)
| [.question, .image_id, .question_id]
| @csv
```

3) To sort by image_id, use sort_by(.image_id)

```
.questions
| sort_by(.image_id)
|.[]
| [.question, .image_id, .question_id]
| @csv
```

4) To group by `.image_id` you would pipe the output of the following pipeline into your own pipeline:

```
.questions | group_by(.image_id)
```

You will, however, have to decide exactly how you want to combine the grouped objects.

Comment: For second answer is it possible to write .question |select(.image_id<=10000)|[.question, .image_id, .question_id]|@csv so that it will return the constrained output?

Comment: In (2), the given filter DOES emit the constrained output!  Have you tried it?

Comment: Hey @peak, thanks it worked all !! Is it possible to extract specific question types from JSON data.Like I want only  question starting with"How","What is", etc..using json.load().

Comment: 5. Consider select(startswith(_)). If you have access to a version of jq with regex support, consider also test/1.

Answer (score 0):

With the `-r` option, the following filter

```
  .questions[] | [ .[] ] | @csv
```

produces

```
"What is the table made of?",350623,3506232
"Is the food napping on the table?",350623,3506230
"What has been upcycled to make lights?",350623,3506231
"Is this an Spanish town?",8647,86472
```

To filter the data, use **select**.  E.g. with the `-r` option the following filter

```
  .questions[] | select(.image_id <= 10000) | [ .[] ] | @csv
```

produces the subset

```
"Is this an Spanish town?",8647,86472
```

To group the data use **group_by**. The following filter

```
    .questions
  | group_by(.image_id)[]
  | [ .[] | [ .[] ] | @csv ]
```

produces grouped data

```
[
  "\"Is this an Spanish town?\",8647,86472"
]
[
  "\"What is the table made of?\",350623,3506232",
  "\"Is the food napping on the table?\",350623,3506230",
  "\"What has been upcycled to make lights?\",350623,3506231"
]
```

This isn't very useful in this form and is probably not exactly what you want but it demonstrates the basic approach.