# How can you get CSV instead of JSON from the HTTP API of InfluxDB?

Tags: json, csv, business-intelligence, influxdb

I want to use an influxdb within the context of business intelligence: 
ETL, joining data from other databases, creating live dashboards.
Right now, we are using standard BI-Tools such as QLIK or Microsoft PowerBI.

According to the documentation the HTTP API should be used for querying (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/guides/querying_data/)
My problem is that the output of the API seems to be JSON only. That means that each analyst first has to figure out how to transform the JSON into table-format before joining other data etc.

Is it possible to tell the API to produce a csv-like table output?
Do you have recommendations which tools to use to produce good Dashboards? I tried grafana but that seemed to fall short when joining other data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `-H "Accept: application/csv"` in your `curl` to have a response in CSV. For instance:

```
$ curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query' --data-urlencode "db=my_db" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT * FROM \"cpu\"" -H "Accept: application/csv"
name,tags,time,host,region,value
cpu,,1493031640435991638,serverA,us_west,0.64
```

Comment: Is that somewhere in the documentation and I just missed it?

Comment: I was following this issue in github: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/pull/7099, that's why I know. But I couldn't find this in the docs either :(

Comment: This feature is described in the manual here: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/tools/api/#request-body

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jq` to convert the JSON output to CSV as follows, which also allows you to get RFC3339 formatted timestamps:

```
jq -r "(.results[0].series[0].columns), (.results[0].series[0].values[]) | @csv"
```

which gives the output

```
"time","ppm","T"
"2019-01-17T19:45:00Z",864.5,18.54
"2019-01-17T19:50:00Z",861.4,18.545
"2019-01-17T19:55:00Z",866.2,18.5
"2019-01-17T20:00:00Z",863.9,18.47
```

and works because:

- `(.results[0].series[0].columns)` gets the column names as array
- `,` concatenates the output
- `(.results[0].series[0].values[])` gets the data values as array
- `| @csv` uses the jq csv formatter
- `-r` is used to get raw output

Further resources:

- Use https://jqplay.org/ to build queries
- Other examples: [Convert JSON array into CSV using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730946/convert-json-array-into-csv-using-jq)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429241/convert-json-to-csv
- [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq#32965227)