# Convert JSON array into CSV using jq

Tags: json, csv, jq

I have JSON file called temp.json.

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "username": "jack",
      "email": "jack@somewhere.com",
      "total running apps": "1",
      "api-mock-app": "0",
      "flogo": "1",
      "ipaas": "0",
      "nodejs-app": "0"
    },
    {
      "username": "jill",
      "email": "jill@somewhere.com",
      "total running apps": "1",
      "api-mock-app": "0",
      "flogo": "1",
      "ipaas": "0",
      "nodejs-app": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

i want to convert this JSON into CSV lilke this,

```
username email              total running apps api-mock-app flogo ipaas nodejs-app
jack     jack@somewhere.com 1                  0            1     0     0
jill     jill@somewhere.com 1                  0            1     0     0
```

I tried this

```
jq -r '.users[] | keys[0] [.username, .email, ."total running apps", ."api-mock-app", .flogo, .ipaas, ."nodejs-app"] | join(", ") | @csv' temp.json`
```

But i am getting error

```
q: error (at temp.json:22): Cannot index string with string "jack"`
```

Can anyone explain where am i making mistake and please let me know the correct answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON into CSV using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715234/convert-a-json-into-csv-using-jq)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**jq** solution:

```
jq -r '(.users[0] | keys_unsorted), (.users[] | to_entries | map(.value))|@csv' temp.json
```

The output:

```
"username","email","total running apps","api-mock-app","flogo","ipaas","nodejs-app"
"jack","jack@somewhere.com","1","0","1","0","0"
"jill","jill@somewhere.com","1","0","1","0","0"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest ways to do it is

```
jq -r "(.users[0] | keys_unsorted),  (.users[] | map(.) | @csv)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it worked perfectly,

```
jq -r '(.users[0] | keys), (.users[] | [.username, .email, ."total running apps", ."api-mock-app", .flogo, .ipaas, ."nodejs-app"]) | @csv' temp.json
```

output format is.

```
"api-mock-app","email","flogo","ipaas","nodejs-app","total running apps","username"
"jack","jack@somewhere.com","1","0","1","0","0"
"jill","jill@somewhere.com","1","0","1","0","0"
```

Comment: but the order of header columns is arbitrary in this case ... and columns don't correspond to subordinate values

Comment: Yeah, I realised that, keys_unsorted would solve this problem as you have rightly answered, Thank You.