# Is there any function that I can export csv file from Chronograf automatically / periodically?

Tags: python, influxdb-python

Now I am using the data which is stored in my local influxDB. I have import the data into Chronograf to visualize the data. From Chronograf, I export the data into python and use python to plot and save the plot into images.

However, all the methods I used are all done by manually. Is there any way that can help me to complete all those methods for example like periodically or automatically update the data and plot it?

Comment: Chronograf is just running influxb queries. You can run the same (or similar) queries from python without involving Chronograf. [Getting Started with Python and InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-python-influxdb/)

Comment: meaning I can straight import data from influxDB into python and maybe using codes to make it read data periodically? My current version of InfluxDB is v1.8.4

Comment: But i use Chronograf is because I want to download the data as csv file, only I can import into my python. I don't know how to straight import my data into python actually.

Comment: If you insist on creating csv files rather than using the python influxdb client (linked in my previous comment), you can use the command line interface `influx` as documented here https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/tools/shell/

Comment: I tried using python influxdb client before, but i think it only support for influxdb v2.0 and above. I have downloaded influxdb v2.0 but I currently don't have the machine for me to collect the data so I cannot use it.

Comment: If you can't use influx CLI then I suggest you use the http API: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43516396/how-can-you-get-csv-instead-of-json-from-the-http-api-of-influxdb