# How to convert json from one format to another using jq

Tags: json, jq

I would like to convert 500+ json files to csv format using the solution provided in [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq) but my json files are not in the same format as per the proposed solution.

Following represents a sample json file:

```
[
  {
    "jou_entry": {
      "id": 655002886,
      "units": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "jou_entry": {
      "id": 655002823,
      "units": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "jou_entry": {
      "id": 657553949,
      "units": 6
    }
  }
]
```

Where as the proposed solution requires the json in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 655002886,
    "units": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 655002823,
    "units": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 657553949,
    "units": 6
  }
]
```

I am able to convert the json from source format to required format using the following jq filter

```
jq -r '[.[] | ."jou_entry"]'
```

But I don't like the hard-coding of key "jou_entry" in the filter. As this will require individual key definition for so many files. I would like to have the conversion without the hard-coded value.

How can I do this? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the desired output

```
jq '[.[] | .[]]'
```

Explanation from the manual. When `.[]` is used on an array, it returns all of the elements of an array. When it is used on an object it will return all the values of the object.

Comment: It could be condensed further to `[.[][]]`.

Comment: So it does! I can't find an example like that in the manual. If it isn't too much trouble, would you please explain how it works? Thanks.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a pipe (`|`) between every simple expression. In a sense, `[]` here is an operand and it is operating on `.`. It's like eliminating `| .` from the end of a filter, it's unnecessary. You could combine many different types of operands on a single expression. e.g., `[to_entries[].key]` instead of `[to_entries | .[] | .key]`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped, I meant to say that `[]` is like an _operator_. Not a big deal, I think you got my drift.

Comment: Right. Thanks again.