# jq: convert JSON file with arrays to CSV - transposed?

Tags: arrays, json, csv, jq

I'm trying to use jq to convert a JSON output to CSV.

Here's input.json (stripped down a lot - I may have up to 600 array elements, but the same number for each):

```
    {
  "latitude": [39.582, 39.582, 39.582],
  "longitude": [26.675, 26.675, 26.675],
  "drivingDifficultyIndex": [0, 34, 34],
  "iconCode": [31, 11, 11],
  "observationTimeUtcIso": ["2016-06-26T00:20:00+0000", "2016-06-26T01:20:00+0000", "2016-06-26T02:20:00+0000"],
  "precip1Hour": [0.0, 0.1, 0.5]
}
```

My best attempt thus far is:

```
jq --raw-output 'keys , .[] | @csv'
```

which makes

```
"drivingDifficultyIndex","iconCode","latitude","longitude","observationTimeUtcIso","precip1Hour"
39.582,39.582,39.582
26.675,26.675,26.675
0,34,34
31,11,11
"2016-06-26T00:20:00+0000","2016-06-26T01:20:00+0000","2016-06-26T02:20:00+0000"
0,0.1,0.5
```

[How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq) gives some good hints, but I still end up with the data in rows (like above) rather than columns.

What I'm after is this:

```
"latitude","longitude","drivingDifficultyIndex","iconCode","observationTimeUtcIso","precip1Hour"
39.582, 26.675, 0,  31, \2016-06-26T00:20:00+0000\",    0
39.582, 26.675, 34, 11, \"2016-06-26T01:20:00+0000\",   0.1
39.582, 26.675, 34, 11, \"2016-06-26T02:20:00+0000\",   0.5
```

With up to 600 elements in each array, I need the CSV file to have a separate column for each array; rows 2 downwards need transposing.

Can someone help jq produce the output I want?

Thanks...

**Update:**

```
jq --raw-output 'keys_unsorted, map(.[0]) , map(.[1]), map(.[2]) |@csv'
```

gives me what I want, for the example 3 array members above. But how can I get this to work to account for much larger (unknown) number of array elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, using `transpose` allows a simple, one-line solution along the lines you envisioned:

```
( keys_unsorted, ([.[]] | transpose)[]) | @csv
```

With the sample data, invocation of jq with the -r option yields:

```
"latitude","longitude","drivingDifficultyIndex","iconCode","observationTimeUtcIso","precip1Hour"
39.582,26.675,0,31,"2016-06-26T00:20:00+0000",0
39.582,26.675,34,11,"2016-06-26T01:20:00+0000",0.1
39.582,26.675,34,11,"2016-06-26T02:20:00+0000",0.5
```

Comment: That is awesome. I'd been trawling through the manual but missed that function! Many thanks...