# How to convert json into csv file using jq?

Tags: json, csv, jq

This is my json file:

```
{
  "ClientCountry": "ca",
  "ClientASN": 812,
  "CacheResponseStatus": 404,
  "CacheResponseBytes": 130756,
  "CacheCacheStatus": "hit"
}
{
  "ClientCountry": "ua",
  "ClientASN": 206996,
  "CacheResponseStatus": 301,
  "CacheResponseBytes": 142,
  "CacheCacheStatus": "unknown"
}
{
  "ClientCountry": "ua",
  "ClientASN": 206996,
  "CacheResponseStatus": 0,
  "CacheResponseBytes": 0,
  "CacheCacheStatus": "unknown"
}
```

I want to convert these json into csv like below.

```
"ClientCountry", "ClientASN","CacheResponseStatus", "CacheResponseBytes", "CacheCacheStatus"
"ca", 812, 404, 130756, "hit";
"ua", 206996, 301, 142,"unknown";
"ua", 206996, 0,0,"unknown";
```

Please let me know how to achieve this using jq?

I just tried below. But its not working.

```
jq 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value] | @csv'
```

Regards
Palani

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you want all the key-values, 
then assuming that the keys are presented in a consistent order in the input file, you can simply write:

```
jq -r '[.[]] | @csv' palanikumar.json
```

With the given input, this produces the following CSV:

```
"ca",812,404,130756,"hit"
"ua",206996,301,142,"unknown"
"ua",206996,0,0,"unknown"
```

Adding the headers and the trailing semicolons (if you really want them) is left as a (very easy) exercise.

### Inconsistent ordering

If the ordering of the keys varies or might vary, then the following could be used to produce suitable CSV, assuming that the ordering of the keys in the first object in the input stream should be used:

```
input
| . as $first
| keys_unsorted as $keys
| $keys, [$first[]], (inputs | [.[$keys[]]]) | @csv
```

The appropriate invocation of jq would include both the -n and -r command-line options.

Comment: Bro I tried a lot to get headers. But couldnt get command to extract headers in csv format. Tried this jq -r 'keys[]' sample.json. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Look at these links

[How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

http://bigdatums.net/2017/09/30/convert-json-to-csv-with-jq/

( jq -r '.myarray | @csv' )

Comment: @Palanikumar You tried adding -r ?                                                                                 ( jq -r )

Comment: Well, check the answer of @peak, and retry

Comment: From what I see, this is the problem [.key, .value]