# using jq, how can I extract a list,an entire list, from a json file for example

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

Given

```
{ "id" :1, 
  "plankVal" : 2,
  "planklist" : ['one','two','three','four']
}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
jq '.planklist' 
one,two,three,four
```

Comment: I feel this question should be reopened. The linked to question is very specific, long and complicated. This general question type (jq -> csv) deserves a simpler question, like this one. Although the title should be improved.

Comment: Ok, I checked and there other worthy duplicate targets, don't understand why this particular target was chosen, makes no sense to me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228126/how-to-convert-json-into-csv-file-using-jq
@peak Please add these as targets instead