# How to convert the simplest JSON to CSV or Text using jq?

Tags: json, csv, jq

My json like this from the command like `curl https://sm.ms/api/upload`:

```
{
  "code": "error",
  "msg": "No files were uploaded."
}
```

**Now I want to get a text like this** (all values of this json):

```
"error", "No files were uploaded."
```

I use the command `curl https://sm.ms/api/upload | jq -r .` but I can only get the json content. The document seems like not to support this funtion.

I search for the web for a long time but there's nothing helpful, so I hope you can help me and thank you~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like to consider a generic solution:

```
jq -r '[.[]] | @csv'
```

Answer (score 4):

The output can be formatted as csv by using the `--raw-output` option:

```
jq --raw-output '"\"\(.code)\", \"\(.msg)\""'
```