# Convert multiple JSON files to a single .CSV file

Tags: json, csv, merge

I am trying to convert 2000 JSON files of the same dimensionality to .csv and merge it to a single .csv file. What would be the best place to look at? Please assist.

Comment: Please give example of source Json file and what do you expect to get in csv file.

Comment: Are you trying to automate this in a particular programming language or just trying to get a one off job done?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here's what one data point looks like in json filet.                                                   {"type":2,"rcvTime":25200.0,"pos":[3587.62730864618,5866.100111525839,1.895],"noise":[0.0,0.0,0.0],"spd":[-0.029183319723886247,30.079023152100438,0.0],"spd_noise":[0.0,0.0,0.0]}                                                                                                  I want to have .csv file generated with "type", "revTime","pos", "noise" etc as attributes in the csv file table.

Comment: There is an nice approach using `jq` already answered in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965227/310441

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of .json files with the same problem.
My solution was to use a bash script to loop all of the files, and use `jq` on each to convert to individual csv files. Something like

```
i=1
for eachFile in /path/to/json/*.json; do
    cat json-$i.json | jq -r '.[] | {column1: .path.to.data, column2: .path.to.data} | [.[] | tostring] | @csv' > extract-$i.csv
    echo "converted $i of many json files..."
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

Then you can `cat` and `>>` all of those in a similar loop to a single .csv file. Something like

```
i=1
for eachFile in /path/to/csv/*.csv; do
    cat extract-$i.csv >> concatenate.csv
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

If you are crafty enough, you can combine those into a single script... edit: in fact, it's just a matter of adding a `>` to the first script, and using a single file name, so `cat json-$i.json | jq -r '.[] | {column1: .path.to.data, column2: .path.to.data} | [.[] | tostring] | @csv' >> output.csv`

Answer (score 0):

There's this great program from Withdata which unfortunately costs a bit of money, but there is a 30 day free trial if you just need a quick fix. Its called DataFileConverter and there is a guide on their website as to how to change json files specifically into .csv. If you're looking for a free program try this repository https://github.com/evidens/json2csv. It's written in python but can still be used with the directions.

Answer (score 0):

Using pathlib and pandas

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

path = "/path/to/files/root/directory/"
files = list(Path(path).rglob("*json.gz"))

pd.concat((pd.read_json(file, compression="gzip") for file in files), ignore_index=True).to_csv(f"{path}/final.csv")
```