# How do I write a jq query to convert a JSON file to CSV?

Tags: json, csv, jq

The JSON files look like:

```js
{
  "name": "My Collection",
  "description": "This is a great collection.",
  "date": 1639717379161,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Sand"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Skin",
      "value": "Dark Brown"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Mouth",
      "value": "Smile Basic"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Eyes",
      "value": "Confused"
    }
  ]  
}
```

I found [a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874996/253756) that uses `jq` and has this code:

```sh
i=1
for eachFile in *.json; do
    cat $i.json | jq -r '.[] | {column1: .name, column2: .description} | [.[] | tostring] | @csv' > extract-$i.csv
    echo "converted $i of many json files..."
    ((i=i+1))
done
```

But its output is:

```shell
jq: error (at <stdin>:34): Cannot index string with string "name"
converted 1 of many json files...
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work? Thank you!

Comment: You didn't adapt the `jq` filter to your actual JSON at all.

Comment: @chepner I updated it to use the `name` and `description` fields. Can you be more specific? I don't understand `jq`.

Comment: You need to write a `jq` command that will convert a given JSON file to CSV. The problem is not your shell script but the invocation of jq.

Comment: @AndyLester Exactly, so how do I write this command? That's why I'm asking Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: @Kane: Could you add an example of the CSV output you want?

Comment: @Kane I've edited your title to reflect the real question.

Comment: We can't tell what sort of transformation you want, but there are many good `jq` tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick jq lesson
===========

jq filters are applied like this:
`jq -r '.name_of_json_field_0 <optional filter>, .name_of_json_field_1 <optional filter>'`
and so on and so forth. A single dot is the simplest filter; it leaves the data field untouched.

`jq -r '.name_of_field .'`

You may also leave the filter field untouched for the same effect.
In your case:
`jq -r '.name, .description'`
will extract the values of both those fields.

`.[]` will unwrap an array to have the next piped filter applied to each unwrapped value. Example:
`jq -r '.attributes | .[]`
extracts all trait_types objects.

You may sometime want to repackage objects in an array by surrounding the filter in brackets:
`jq -r '[.name, .description, .date]`

You may sometime want to repackage data in an object by surrounding the filter in curly braces:
`jq -r '{new_field_name: .name, super_new_field_name: .description}'

playing around with these, I was able to get

```sh
jq -r '[.name, .description, .date, (.attributes | [.[] | .trait_type] | @csv | gsub(",";";") | gsub("\"";"")), (.attributes | [.[] | .value] | .[]] | @csv | gsub(",";";") | gsub("\"";""))] | @csv'
```

to give us:
`"My Collection","This is a great collection.",1639717379161,"Background;Skin;Mouth;Eyes","Sand;Dark Brown;Smile Basic;Confused"`

Name, description, and date were left as is, so let's break down the weird parts, one step at a time.

`.attributes | [.[] | .trait_type]`
`.[]` extracts each element of the attributes array and pipes the result of that into the next filter, which says to simply extract `trait_type`, where they are re-packaged in an array.

`.attributes | [.[] | .trait_type] | @csv`
turn the array into a csv-parsable format.

`(.attributes | [.[] | .trait_type] | @csv | gsub(",";";") | gsub("\"";""))`
Parens separate this from the rest of the evaluations, obviously.
The first `gsub` here replaces commas with semicolons so they don't get interpreted as a separate field, the second removes all extra double quotes.