# jq get all values in a tabbed format

Tags: json, jq

i'm trying to convert a json to a tab formatted data:

```
{"level":"INFO", "logger":"db", "msg":"connection successful"}
{"level":"INFO", "logger":"server", "msg":"server started"}
{"level":"INFO", "logger":"server", "msg":"listening on port :4000"}
{"level":"INFO", "logger":"server", "msg":"stopping s ervices ..."}
{"level":"INFO", "logger":"server", "msg":"exiting..."}
```

to something like this:

```
INFO   db       connection successful
INFO   server   server started
INFO   server   listening on port 4000
DEBUG  server   stopping s ervices ...
INFO   server   exiting...
```

I've tried this `jq -r ' . | to_entries[] | "\(.value)"'`, but this prints each value on a separate line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert arbirtrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

Comment: and use `jq ... file | column -t -s, -o$'\t'` to have it tab formatted

Comment: @oliv, I tried those but didn't work. some give errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the keys are always in the same order, you could get away with:

```
jq -r '[.[]]|@tsv'
```

In any case, it would be preferable to use `@tsv`.

Comment: does tsv support color too?