# Structured JSON to CSV with jq

Tags: json, csv, nested, export-to-csv, jq

Using `jq` I try to convert a JSON to CSV. Here's how my input JSON looks like:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "a": ["x","y"],
      "b": "some",
      "c": "string"
    },
    {
      "a": ["u","v"],
      "b": "another",
      "c": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired output is like:

```
a   | b       | c
x y | some    | string
u v | another | string
```

**Edit:** And for those complaining that this wouldn't be valid CSV, here in RFC 4180 compliant syntax:

```
a,b,c
x y,some,string
u v,another,string
```

Using `.rows`, I successfully get the array:

```
[{"a":["x","y"],"b":"some","c":"string"},{"a":["u","v"],"b":"another","c":"string"}]
```

But `.rows | @csv` says: `object ({"a":["x","...) is not valid in a csv row`. So, I somehow have to join the array in key "a".

Using `.rows[] | .a | join(" ")` I get:

```
"x y"
"u v"
```

But how do I get this back into my JSON to then use `... | @csv` to get my desired CSV data?

Comment: That's why I wrote "output is like". I chose that table-like presentation to make it more obvious what output structure I'd expect, hoping it would be easier for the readers. But I have now added the the expected CSV in RFC 4180 compliant syntax.

Comment: Probably functions like flatten or transpose can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your input, the following [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) program:

```
.rows[]
| map_values(if type == "array" then join(" ") else . end)
| [.[]]
| @csv
```

produces the comma-separated-values output:

```
"x y","some","string"
"u v","another","string"
```

It's a simple matter to add the headers, so I'll leave that to you.  Also, let me point out that since you specified CSV output, using `@csv` is strongly advised, but if for some reason you want to avoid those sometimes-superfluous quotation marks, you can fiddle with the string-valued values to insert the quotation marks as needed, and then use `join(",")` instead of `@csv`.

Alternatively, you might like to weave `@tsv` into your solution.

### Caveat

The solution above assumes the a/b/c keys are in the same order throughout, and that the objects have no additional keys, etc.  If safety is an issue, then simply modify the line `[.[]]` in the program to specify exactly what you want.

### See also:

For some ideas about handling headers, ensuring consistency, and genericity, see:

[jq: Object cannot be csv-formatted, only array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242240/jq-object-cannot-be-csv-formatted-only-array)

Comment: Works great, thank you! But I had a hard time to get it working on my command line (on macOS). With copy'n'paste I always got an "unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER" error. Not only on my command line, but also on the jq playground. Typing the command by myself fixed that problem. Here's the command line that finally worked for me: `jq -r '.rows[] | map_values(if type == "array" then join(" ") else . end) | [.[]] | @csv' < test.json`

Answer (score 0):

A bit complicated is you want to **rotate** output.
Tab delimitted output printed in console, but looks like desired **except pipes**:

```js
function rotate2CSV(inp) {
  var cols = {}; // will be collected in originalKey:[column values]
  for(var rowNo=0;rowNo<inp.rows.length;rowNo++) {
      var rowData = inp.rows[rowNo];
      for(var colsData in rowData) {
          if(!cols[colsData])  cols[colsData] = [];
          cols[colsData].push(rowData[colsData])
      }
  }
  var res = [[]]; // colls rotated content [header keys], [1st row content], ...
  for(var colsData in cols) {
    var col = res[0].indexOf(colsData);
    if(col < 0) {
      col = res[0].length;
      res[0].push(colsData);
    }
    if(col > -1) {
      for(var row=0;row<cols[colsData].length;row++) {
        if(res.length - 1 <= row) res.push([]);
        var cell = cols[colsData][row];
        if(cell instanceof Array) cell = cell.join(' ');
        res[row+1].push(cell);
      }

    }
  }
  for(var rowNo=0;rowNo<res.length;rowNo++) {
    console.log(res[rowNo].join('\t'))
  }
}
rotate2CSV(
  {
    "rows": [
        {
            "a": ["x", "y"],
            "b": "some",
            "c": "string"
        },
        {
            "a": ["u", "v"],
            "b": "another",
            "c": "string"
        }
    ]
  }
);
```

Comment: This is JS code, isn't it? I'm looking for a solution using the command line tool `jq`.

Comment: Sorry, thought jQuery, anyway you can translate it in case it is such simple as JS ;-) But rotation could be hard - maybe C# / .net core could be much easier.

Comment: Should I delete my JS answer ?

Comment: @peak <=27 max to compare comparable ;-) and real work behind curtains should hopefully be easier(?)