# how to avoid duplicated record while json import+ salesforce sfdx

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc, sfdc-metadata-api, sfdx

I would like to import contact records but i see some of the duplicate records are inserting. I know there is a option to avoid the duplicating is "External ID" through importing wizard. But here, i'm importing the data using JSON but not sure how to prevent to import the data which i had in the json.

Comment: does it have to be json format, CSV loads with force:data:bulk:upsert would let you specify the external id column. You'd have to load them 1 table at a time though so Accounts, then Contacts, then Cases... If your source absolutely has to be JSON - maybe you could convert it to csv using jq? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57242240/313628

Comment: Create an external ID as a formula field. The formula could be just first name and last name. But should contain everything you use to consider duplicate. Then if 2 contacts create the same external ID the second one won't insert.