# How to produce a flat list of all values from a given JSON

Tags: json, jq, flatten, json-flattener

I would like to produce a list of all values from any given JSON. The special requirement is that for values in nested attributes, all the values of parent's attributes must be repeated in the line. No keys must be printed.

For example, from this input JSON:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "id":306,
         "name":"First Company",
         "branches":[
            {
               "id":4191,
               "city":"Seattle",
               "customers":[
                  {
                     "id":446,
                     "name":"Big Tech 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":447,
                     "name":"Big Tech 2"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":4192,
               "city":"Oakland",
               "customers":[
                  {
                     "id":448,
                     "name":"Health Tech 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":449,
                     "name":"Health Tech 2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to produce this output (please notice the repeated values are highlighted in red, but the output should be with no colors; no keys should be printed):

[image]

The JSON above is just an example and generic JSON with arbitrary depth of nesting of JSON objects must be assumed, which suggests that the processing must be recursive. If *null* appears they must be printed as well.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate and nest:

```bash
jq -r '
  .results[] | [.id, .name] + (
    .branches[] | [.id, .city] + (
      .customers[] | [.id, .name]
    )
  ) | @tsv
'
```

```
306 First Company   4191    Seattle 446 Big Tech 1
306 First Company   4191    Seattle 447 Big Tech 2
306 First Company   4192    Oakland 448 Health Tech 1
306 First Company   4192    Oakland 449 Health Tech 2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/kGqGKrRrxAG)

To keep the values JSON-encoded (quotes around strings), you could re-convert them using `@json`

```bash
jq -r '
  .results[] | [.id, .name] + (
    .branches[] | [.id, .city] + (
      .customers[] | [.id, .name]
    )
  ) | map(@json) | @tsv
'
```

```
306 "First Company" 4191    "Seattle"   446 "Big Tech 1"
306 "First Company" 4191    "Seattle"   447 "Big Tech 2"
306 "First Company" 4192    "Oakland"   448 "Health Tech 1"
306 "First Company" 4192    "Oakland"   449 "Health Tech 2"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H6OLyJ4F7vw)

Alternatively (to the JSON encoding), you could use the `@csv` builtin, which also escapes strings but also separates the items with a comma:

```bash
jq -r '
  .results[] | [.id, .name] + (
    .branches[] | [.id, .city] + (
      .customers[] | [.id, .name]
    )
  ) | @csv
'
```

```
306,"First Company",4191,"Seattle",446,"Big Tech 1"
306,"First Company",4191,"Seattle",447,"Big Tech 2"
306,"First Company",4192,"Oakland",448,"Health Tech 1"
306,"First Company",4192,"Oakland",449,"Health Tech 2"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/YdkLeG6yPOC)

Comment: I guess, we should not hard-code attribute names like `.id, .name ...`, it's about general parent/nested attrs

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, Yes!  @romanperekhrest is right. The JSON in the question was only an example. It should work for any given JSON.
In fact I am receiving an error when using a real JSON:
`jq: error (at real-case.json:3467): Cannot iterate over null (null)`

Answer (score 1):

The following makes various assumptions but only hardcodes "results", "branches" and "customers",
and does *not* assume that the ordering of the keys within the customer objects is uniform.
Using `scalar_keys` in the obvious way, the solution can also be readily extended to allow for greater depth, and
indeed could be generalized to compute the array-valued keys.

```
def scalar_keys:
  [ keys_unsorted[] as $k
    | .[$k]
    | scalars
    | $k ];
    
.results[]
| [.[scalar_keys[]] ] as $top
| .branches[]
| [.[scalar_keys[]] ] as $intermediate
| .customers
| (first | keys_unsorted) as $keys
| .[]
| $top + $intermediate + [.[$keys[]]]
```

This produces arrays, so you will want to tack on a call to `@tsv` or `@csv` or similar.

Comment: Do you want your last line to be [something like `| $top + $intermediate + [.[$keys[]]]`](https://jqplay.org/s/G3PtsQAw4If "link to jqplay.org -->")?

Comment: Thanks a lot! however, I must deal with different JSON structures. In fact, It's been a challenge for me to try a command to deal with generic JSON with different structures and arbitrary depths.

Comment: @DenioMariz - If you cannot adapt the solution here to your needs, then consider the generic JSON-to-CSV programs at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57242240/jq-object-cannot-be-csv-formatted-only-array, esp. json2csv

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution that does not depend on the structure of the JSON ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PJ0FxaegKX4), [another demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QYagHsDTxBY)):

```
def unroll:
    if type == "object" 
    then [.[] | scalars] + ((.[] | iterables | unroll) // [] ) 
    elif type == "array" 
    then (.[] | unroll)
    else [.] 
    end;
    
unroll | @tsv
```

It recursively descends through the object graph, but when it encounters an object, it extracts all the scalars so that on the way up (in the recursion), the scalars in the path become one array. When an array is encountered though, it just acts as a pass-through and unrolls the array.