# jq - converting json to cvs - how to treat "null" as string?

Tags: json, csv, null, export-to-csv, jq

I have the following json file which I would like to convert to csv:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2014-05-05T19:07:48.577"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "date": null
}
```

Converting it to csv with the following jq produces:

```
$ jq -sr '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' < test.json
"date","id"
"2014-05-05T19:07:48.577",1
,2
```

Unfortunately, for the line with "id" equal to "2", the date column was not set to "null" - instead, it was empty. This in turn makes MySQL error on import if it's a datetime column (it expects a literal "null" if we don't have a date, and errors on "").

How can I make jq print the literal "null", and not ""?

Comment: I've edited in the `-s` option so that the question, example input and output are all consistent. If that wasn't the intent, feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with:

```
(map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique) as $cols
| $cols,
  (.[] | [.[$cols[]]] | map(. // "null") )
| @csv
```

First, using `keys_unsorted` avoids useless sorting.

Second, `[.[$cols[]]]` is an important, recurrent and idiomatic pattern, used to ensure an array is constructed in the correct order without resorting to the `reduce` sledge-hammer.

Third, although `map(. // "null")` seems to be appropriate here, it should be noted that this expression will also replace `false` with `"null"`, so, it would not be appropriate in general. Instead, to preserve `false`, one could write `map(if . == null then "null" else . end)`.

Fourth, it should be noted that using `map(. // "null")` as above will also mask missing values of any of the keys, so if one wants some other behavior (e.g., raising an error if `id` is missing), then an alternative approach would be warranted.

---

The above assumes the stream of JSON objects shown in the question is "slurped", e.g. using jq's -s command-line option.

Comment: That idiom is one I had not encountered yet - nice! @Tomasz - if you want the value `false` to convert to "null", use `// "null"` as above; if you want `false` to convert to "false", then replace `// "null"` with `| tostring` (though that would also stringify numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Use `//` as alternative operator for your cell value:

`jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.] // "null")) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' < test.json`

(The whole string is pretty good explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965227/16174836)

Answer (score 1):

You can "stringify" the value using [`tostring`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tostring) by changing `map($row[.])` into `map($row[.]|tostring)`:

```
$ cat so2332.json
{
  "id": 1,
  "date": "2014-05-05T19:07:48.577"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "date": null
}

$ jq --slurp --raw-output '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.]|tostring)) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' so2332.json
"date","id"
"2014-05-05T19:07:48.577","1"
"null","2"
```

Note that the use of `tostring` will cause the numbers to be converted to strings.

Comment: As is evident from the example, using `tostring` for all the keys causes the `id` to become a CSV string, which may be undesirable.

Comment: Indeed -- I mentioned that in a comment on your answer, but didn't mention it here. I will add a note.