# jq - select objects and print null for missing

Tags: json, csv, export-to-csv, jq

I'm trying to generate a CSV of sort from json file, the files are as below

```
cat role1.json
{
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "Role1Name"
    },
    {
      "Key": "ID",
      "Value": "Role1ID"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Manager",
      "Value": "Role1Manager"
    },
    {
      "Key": "User",
      "Value": "Role1User"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Country",
      "Value": "USA"
    }
  ]
}

cat role2.json
{
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "Role2Name"
    },
    {
      "Key": "ID",
      "Value": "Role2ID"
    },
    {
      "Key": "City",
      "Value": "NewYork"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Creator",
      "Value": "Role2Creator"
    },
    {
      "Key": "User",
      "Value": "Role2User"
    }
  ]
}

cat role3.json
{
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "Role3Name"
    },
    {
      "Key": "ID",
      "Value": "Role3ID"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Creator",
      "Value": "Role3Creator"
    },
    {
      "Key": "ZIP",
      "Value": 82378
    },
    {
      "Key": "Manager",
      "Value": "Role3Manager"
    },
    {
      "Key": "User",
      "Value": "Role3User"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to generate lines from each of these to be later used as CSV, something like:

```
Role1Name, Role1ID, null, Role1Manager, Role1User
Role2Name, Role2ID, Role2Creator, null, Role2User
Role3Name, Role3ID, Role3Creator, Role3Manager, Role3User
```

For the header line
Name, ID, Creator, Manager, User

I'm able to get all the "Value" but not able to print null for missing "Key"

```
$cat role1.json | jq -rc  '[.Tags[] | select(.Key == ("Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User")) | .Value]'
["Role1Name","Role1ID","Role1Manager","Role1User"]

$cat role2.json | jq -rc  '[.Tags[] | select(.Key == ("Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User")) | .Value]'
["Role2Name","Role2ID","Role2Creator","Role2User"]

$cat role3.json | jq -rc  '[.Tags[] | select(.Key == ("Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User")) | .Value]'
["Role3Name","Role3ID","Role3Creator","Role3Manager","Role3User"]
```

Can someone share with me how this can be done using jq.

Also, how can we enforce the order.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key (ha!) is

```
[ .[ $keys[] ] ]
```

Had you looked at other answers to questions relating to CSV, you might have noticed the first step taken is to get the list of keys. This is often done by collecting the keys of the input objects. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68043093/589924)) In your case, you have a hard-coded list, so it's even simpler.

---

If you wanted actual CSV, you could use

```sh
jq -sr '
   [ "Name", "ID", "Creator", "Manager", "User" ] as $keys |
   (
      $keys,
      ( .[].Tags | from_entries | [ .[ $keys[] ] ] )
   ) |
   @csv
' role*.json
```

This produces

```
"Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User"
"Role1Name","Role1ID",,"Role1Manager","Role1User"
"Role2Name","Role2ID","Role2Creator",,"Role2User"
"Role3Name","Role3ID","Role3Creator","Role3Manager","Role3User"
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/uRVe24KPt1)

Without a header:

```sh
jq -r '.Tags | from_entries | [ .["Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User"] ] | @csv' role*.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/5Li2gdZrAa)

---

To get the specific output you posted (which isn't CSV), you could use

```sh
jq -sr '
   [ "Name", "ID", "Creator", "Manager", "User" ] as $keys |
   (
      $keys,
      ( .[].Tags | from_entries | [ .[ $keys[] ] | . // "null" ] )
   ) |
   join(", ")
' role*.json
```

This produces

```
Name, ID, Creator, Manager, User
Role1Name, Role1ID, null, Role1Manager, Role1User
Role2Name, Role2ID, Role2Creator, null, Role2User
Role3Name, Role3ID, Role3Creator, Role3Manager, Role3User
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/MCcHV7Q1Yx)

Without a header:

```sh
jq -r '.Tags | from_entries | [ .["Name","ID","Creator","Manager","User"] | . // "null" ] | join(", ")' role*.json
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/TjmhrSvYes)

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from another forum, might be useful for others

```
$jq -rc  '.Tags | from_entries | [.Name, .ID, .Creator, .Manager, .User]' role*.json
["Role1Name","Role1ID",null,"Role1Manager","Role1User"]
["Role2Name","Role2ID","Role2Creator",null,"Role2User"]
["Role3Name","Role3ID","Role3Creator","Role3Manager","Role3User"]
```

Comment: That's neither CSV nor the format requested in the OP, though. Is there an error in the question or in the answer?

Comment: Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami. Your answer is helpful, I just wanted to post the other response. I agree it is not the same, thanks again.