# csv to json or json format as column array command line

Tags: json, linux, csv, command-line, jq

is it possible to obtain this output ?
With a command line tool (jq or other)

From csv

```
id,age,gender
1,39,M
2,25,M
```

To json column array

```json
[{"id":["1","2"]},{"age":["39","25"]},{"gender":["M","M"]}]
```

OR from json

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "age": "39",
        "gender": "M"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "age": "25",
        "gender": "M"
    }
]
```

To json column array

```json
[{"id":["1","2"]},{"age":["39","25"]},{"gender":["M","M"]}]
```

Hoping you understood me. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert arbitrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)

Comment: What did you try? What tools did you already consider and how did you fail?

Comment: I have tried jq but not the skills to find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cannonical way to read in CSV as the format is not standardized. Existing usages mostly differ in the field separator and the escape sequence (used if either one happens to be part of the data), which you would have to consider explicitly when reading in raw text manually.

Therefore, I regard it as safer to follow your second approach. Here's one way for the given input:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "age": "39",
        "gender": "M"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "age": "25",
        "gender": "M"
    }
]
```

```bash
jq 'map(to_entries) | transpose | map({(first.key): map(.value)}) | add'
```

```json
{
  "id": [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  "age": [
    "39",
    "25"
  ],
  "gender": [
    "M",
    "M"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/iHYGijtHtXK)

Comment: @oguz_ismail - Please undelete your useful answer, though I'd suggest adding a `caveat emptor`.