# How can I use jq to filter only certain fields of the original JSON into an CSV?

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I say [this stack overflow anser with a simple jq command to convert a JSON to a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32965227), but I need to improve it further.

Say I have the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "env": "dev",
        "version": "1.24"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "env": "staging",
        "version": "1.21"
    },
    {
        "name": "boo",
        "env": "prod",
        "version": "1.23"
    },
    {
        "name": "far",
        "env": "prod",
        "version": "1.24"
    }
]
```

How does one create the CSV with only the "name" and "version" fields?

My current command is:

```
jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(.[] | {name, version} as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv'
```

This is not working. Can anyone provide some help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the two column names anyway, you could simply extract them directly using `.name` and `.version`:

```bash
<file jq -r '["name", "version"], (.[] | [.name, .version]) | @csv'
```

You can also use your `$cols` variable, so the names only appear once:

```bash
<file jq -r '["name", "version"] as $cols | $cols, (.[] | [.[$cols[]]]) | @csv'
```

Or import them dynamically, e.g. using `--args`:

```bash
<file jq -r '$ARGS.positional, (.[] | [.[$ARGS.positional[]]]) | @csv' \
  --args name version
```

Output:

```
"name","version"
"foo","1.24"
"bar","1.21"
"boo","1.23"
"far","1.24"
```