# Convert JSON from Gitlab to CSV with JQ

Tags: json, csv, gitlab, jq

I am currently trying to create a json convert job in gitlab and I am running into issues with jq.

The following is the output from gitlab after doing container scanning and I am trying to convert it to a csv by using jq to get the information I want.

This is so I can include a readable csv as a build artifact.

```json
"vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "CVE-2015-5186",
      "category": "container_scanning",
      "message": "Audit: log terminal emulator escape sequences handling",
      "description": "Audit before 2.4.4 in Linux does not sanitize escape characters in filenames.",
      "cve": "CVE-2015-5186",
      "severity": "Medium",
      "solution": "No solution provided",
      "scanner": {
        "id": "trivy",
        "name": "trivy"
      },
      "location": {
        "dependency": {
          "package": {
            "name": "audit-libs"
          },
          "version": "2.8.5-4.el7"
        },
        "operating_system": "Unknown",
        "image": "image.tar"
      },
      "identifiers": [
        {
          "type": "cve",
          "name": "CVE-2015-5186",
          "value": "CVE-2015-5186",
          "url": "example.com"
        }
      ],
      "links": [{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        },{
          "url": "example.com"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The following is my current jq statement and I am not sure what I am missing to make this work.

```yaml
- echo "id, message, description, severity, name, version, identifiers" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/${IMAGENAME}-trivy.csv

- jq -r '.vulnerabilities | map([.id, .message, .description, .severity, (.location | .dependency, .package, .name), (.location | .dependency, .version), (.identifiers | .0, .type), (.identifiers | .0, .name), (.identifiers | .0, .value), (.identifiers | .0, .url)] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/gl-container-scanning-report.json >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/${IMAGENAME}-trivy.csv
```

which results in

```yaml
$ jq -r '.vulnerabilities | map([.id, .message, .description, .severity, (.location | .dependency, .package, .name), (.location | .dependency, .version), (.identifiers | .0, .type), (.identifiers | .0, .name), (.identifiers | .0, .value), (.identifiers | .0, .url)] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/gl-container-scanning-report.json >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/${IMAGENAME}-trivy.csv
jq: error (at /builds/group/subgroup/project/reports/gl-container-scanning-report.json:34424): Cannot index array with string "type"
```

I have also tried slightly modifying to remove the identifiers which resulted in this.

```yaml
$ echo "id, message, description, severity, name, version" > $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/${IMAGENAME}-trivy.csv
$ jq -r '.vulnerabilities | map([.id, .message, .description, .severity, (.location | .dependency, .package, .name), (.location | .dependency, .version)] | join(", ")) | join("\n")' $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/gl-container-scanning-report.json >> $CI_PROJECT_DIR/reports/${IMAGENAME}-trivy.csv
jq: error (at /builds/jdiss/fdtm/galelisten/reports/gl-container-scanning-report.json:34424): string ("CVE-2015-5...) and object ({"package":...) cannot be added
```

I am trying to figure out the location stuff so I can get the package name and its version.

I am also trying to get the identifiers information.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: Is this [jqplay.org example](https://jqplay.org/s/0hqrrNM1cSj) or [this example](https://jqplay.org/s/pjdMrMoxHIT) close to what you want?

Comment: Please fix your example to be actually valid JSON

Comment: It's unclear why you add multiple zeros to your output (`.0` is just `0` (`0.0`)) or why you access fields that don't exist at that level

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the usage of [`.` (object identifier-index)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#ObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo,.foo.bar), [`,` (comma)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Comma:,), and [`|` (pipe)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Pipe:%7C).

If you want to access the `package` of the following JSON object:

```json
{
  "location": {
    "dependency": {
      "package": {
        "name": "audit-libs"
      },
      "version": "2.8.5-4.el7"
    },
    "operating_system": "Unknown",
    "image": "image.tar"
  }
}
```

the syntax is `.location | .dependency | .package` or `.location.dependency.package` (but not `.location, .dependency, .package`; the latter is a stream of 3 properties all from the same level in your JSON).

Elements of an array are accessed with `[0]` and not with `.0` (`.0` is the decimal number `0.0`).

---

Now, if you want CSV, it is easier to use the builtin `@csv` filter. You don't need that `echo` for the headers either, `jq` can add the headers just fine:

```
["id", "message", "description", "severity", "name", "version", "identifiers"],
(
    .vulnerabilities[]
    | [
      .id,
      .message,
      .description,
      .severity,
      (.location.dependency | .package.name, .version),
      (.identifiers[0] | .type, .name, .value, .url)
    ]
) | @csv
```

(Raw) output:

```
"id","message","description","severity","name","version","identifiers"
"CVE-2015-5186","Audit: log terminal emulator escape sequences handling","Audit before 2.4.4 in Linux does not sanitize escape characters in filenames.","Medium","audit-libs","2.8.5-4.el7","cve","CVE-2015-5186","CVE-2015-5186","example.com"
```

Further reading: [How to convert arbitrary simple JSON to CSV using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq)