# How to convert specific JSON file to CSV file

Tags: json, jq, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a very large JSON file (zip compressed: [full_ip-port.json](https://threatfox.abuse.ch/export/json/ip-port/full/)) to CSV.

The file consists of a single JSON object that has a regular structure.  Here is a representative extract (obtained by `[to_entries[0,1]] | from_entries`):

```
{
  "1122595": [
    {
      "ioc_value": "103.100.159.212:443",
      "ioc_type": "ip:port",
      "threat_type": "botnet_cc",
      "malware": "win.cobalt_strike",
      "malware_alias": "Agentemis,BEACON,CobaltStrike,cobeacon",
      "malware_printable": "Cobalt Strike",
      "first_seen_utc": "2023-05-27 02:31:39",
      "last_seen_utc": null,
      "confidence_level": 100,
      "reference": null,
      "tags": "CLOUDIE-AS-AP Cloudie Limited,CobaltStrike,cs-watermark-666666",
      "anonymous": "0",
      "reporter": "drb_ra"
    }
  ],
  "1122593": [
    {
      "ioc_value": "167.172.72.193:23",
      "ioc_type": "ip:port",
      "threat_type": "botnet_cc",
      "malware": "elf.bashlite",
      "malware_alias": "gayfgt,Gafgyt,qbot,torlus,lizkebab",
      "malware_printable": "Bashlite",
      "first_seen_utc": "2023-05-27 01:40:04",
      "last_seen_utc": null,
      "confidence_level": 75,
      "reference": "https://bazaar.abuse.ch/sample/6c901ba15327da68159712a9726807fb08868309726c55ef202818bfde22a5a7/",
      "tags": "Gafgyt",
      "anonymous": "0",
      "reporter": "abuse_ch"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I have so far:

Inner Part:

```
jq -r '.[] | .[] | to_entries | map(.value) | @csv' full_ip-port.json
```

Missing ID:

```
jq -r '{id: (. | keys[])} | to_entries | map(.value) | @csv' full_ip-port.json
```

How can I bring it together to a nice and clean CSV file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] (minimal!). Nobody likes to download files from external sites from sites with questionable domain names.

Comment: Also, might already be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbitrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your example is sufficiently uniform, you could get away with:

```
jq -r '
  to_entries
  | (.[0].value[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys
  | .[]
  | .key as $key
  | .value[]
  | [$key, .[$keys[]] ]
  | @csv
'
```

With your input, the first row would be:

```
"1122595","103.100.159.212:443","ip:port","botnet_cc","win.cobalt_strike","Agentemis,BEACON,CobaltStrike,cobeacon","Cobalt Strike","2023-05-27 02:31:39",,100,,"CLOUDIE-AS-AP Cloudie Limited,CobaltStrike,cs-watermark-666666","0","drb_ra"
```

You could also use `["key"] + $keys` (for example) to produce a CVS header:

```
to_entries
| (.[0].value[0]|keys_unsorted) as $keys
| ["key"] + $keys,
  (.[]
   | .key as $key
   | .value[]
  | [$key, .[$keys[]] ])
| @csv
```

Comment: Having the header too would be nice. May you share the full command? Thx

Comment: I simply used: echo '"ioc_id","ioc_value","ioc_typ","threat_type","malware","malware_alias","malware_printable","first_seen_utc","last_seen_utc","confidence_level","reference","tags","anonymous","reporter"'